# Can't catch errors from ember backgroundReload

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

Let's says we have a `UsersIndexRoute` where we load all users.

```
model() {
  return this.store.findAll('users');
}
```

When we load the page for the first time (hard reload) and get a `HTTP 500 error`back we get this error in the `ApplicationRoute`'s `errors()` and can render a error page and everything is fine.

**But:** 
Let's says we already loaded the Ember App but only loaded a subset of all users, go to the `/users` page and call the `findAll` again, Ember immediately gives back the subset of users we already loaded in the store and fetches all the other users in a background request.

Now in our case we get a `HTTP 500 error` back in the backgroundReload, but it seems like https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L1027 doesn't return the promise array back and we can't catch the error in our `findAll` method anymore, or receiving any error in the `ApplicationRoute`'s `error()`.

My question is: how and where can I catch errors from backgroundReload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the GH Issue that discusses the topic and also gives a "solution" to the problem: https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/3809

Answer (score 1):

You can catch any error using `.then()` [method](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/RSVP.Promise.html#method_then):

```
model() {
  return this.store.findAll('users')
      .then(null, (error) => {/*do smth*/});
}
```

Comment: Generally yes, but in this particular case we don't get the promise from the backgroundReload, we only get it from the store (cached) data. If there would be a return in this line: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L1027 it would work (tested).

Comment: In this case, I don't see a workaround other than forcing ember to reload data, as shown [here](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/18/ember-data-1-13-released.html#toc_better-caching-defaults-for-code-findall-code-and-code-findrecord-code): `return this.store.findAll('users', { reload: true });`